# cordova-plugin-image-picker and com-sarriaroman-photoviewer not works in iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 SE

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I made ionic based mobile application.

I used `cordova-plugin-image-picker` plugin for uploading image.

I used `com-sarriaroman-photoviewer` plugin for viewing image.

Both plugins are working in andorid.

But they are not working in iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 SE (iOS 10+).

I don't know the reason why such happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i solved it. just add below tag to your `index.html`. it solved my issue.

if do you have same tag please remove it and replace it with this tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src gap://ready *; style-src &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos;; script-src &apos;self&apos; https://maps.googleapis.com https://*.googleapis.com &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; &apos;unsafe-eval&apos;">
```